# Python3 pickling an object; its boolean attribute are not properly unpickled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, marshalling

I have a class, that can serialize itself, using the `pickle` module.

This class has some attributes, that are initialized as `False`:

```
class A():
    _bool_attribute = False
```

Getters and setters are set, and used, like this:

```
@property
    def bool_attribute(self):
        return self._bool_attribute

@bool_attribute.setter
    def bool_attribute(self, b):
        self._bool_attribute = b
```

The has a few method that change those attributes, like so:

```
def method_ex(self):
    self.bool_attribute = True
```

However, when "saving" and "restoring" using pickle, the attribute value is not consistent:

```
>>> s = A()
>>> s.method_ex()
>>> s.bool_attribute
True
>>> s.save()
>>> t = A()
>>> t.load()
>>> t.bool_attribute
False
```

"Saving" and "loading" is done simply like this:

```
def save(self):
    pickle.dump(self, open("file", "wb"))

def load(self):
    self = pickle.load(open("file"), "rb))
```

Why are the attribute value not both `True`? How can I properly pickle that value as with the rest of the class?

Comment: ``self = pickle.load(open("file"), "rb)`` assigns the loaded object to the *local* variable ``self``, which is reclaimed immediately afterwards. You must either set the state of the loaded object *on* ``self`` or return what you loaded.

Comment: Your `load()` method does absolutely nothing.  It unpicks the saved data into a local variable, which then vanishes at the end of the function.  To make it work, you'd need to manually copy all attributes from the loaded object into the original `self`.  The normal way to implement functionality like this would be a static or class method, that returned the loaded data.